# Tkinter, button to save data in a file

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a file that recopiles all the results of my code. I achieved to create the file, but it's empty. I used tkinter to choose file directory and it's okey, but then to write the results into logText I am struggling.

Here is my code:

```
root4 = tk.Tk() 
root4.geometry('200x150') 


def writeLogfile():
    logText=('Slug Test Analysis Results')
    logText = logText + '\n***Identifying Start of Slug Test***\n'+'Start at t = ' + str(t_0) + ' s'
    logText = logText + 'Number of slug test pipe used: '+ str(user_pipes) + '\n\n'
    with open('Results' + '_logfile' + '.dat', 'w') as output:    
        output.write(logText)

logText = writeLogfile()




savedata_button = tk.Button(root4, text = 'Save Slug Test analysis', command =  writeLogfile) 
savedata_button.pack(side = 'top', pady = 20) 
tk.mainloop()
```

It appears does not appear any other error, but no saving the data in a file.

Comment: How does `writeLogfile()` gain access to `t_0` and `user_pipes`?

You don't need the `lambda` in the command section of your button, since no values are passed to `writeLogfile`. Can be rewritten as: `command=writeLogfile` (unless you are planning on feeding in parameters later on.

Comment: The variables t_0 and user_pipes are defined in otherparts of the code. I erased lambda and typed command=writeLogfile. I don't get an error but, once I push the butto it does nothing

Comment: You should replace `return logText` by `with open(...) ...` block.

Comment: I edited as u said and gives no error but it's not creatig any file and not saving the results

Comment: I got the output file with your updated code.  Also `logText = writeLogfile()` should be removed as it will create the output file when the script is executed.